# unordered_map vs vector with int keys

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

What is the difference in performance between using an `std::unordered_map` or a `std::vector` when the keys are integers. I have around 100-1000 elements which have continuous IDs that I can use to access a vector. The reason to use a hash table is that is more convenient to index by the objects themselves.

Imagine three different situations:

- Write intensive
- Read intensive
- Balanced

Note that I ask it as a general question, no as a code specific one.

Comment: The only way to know is to implement both, compile with optimizations on and profile. My bets would be on `std::vector`, because it would have less cache-misses, but it's just a guess.

Comment: The best way to answer that question is to try it yourself. Performance characteristics of standard containers may vary by implementation, and the hardware youre running on may also affect results.

Comment: This really depends on what you are using it for. Inserts not at the end of a vector are slow. Iterations over a vector are significantly faster.

Comment: Accessing vectors by index is generally faster than accessing map by index, but there are so many things that could be problematic here (random insertions? deletions? mixing of reads and writes? density of keys? linear or random access pattern?). Profile both and then decide. That will also tell you if this is even relevant for performance.

Comment: For convenience: Just add a function taking references to the vector and an object that indexes the vector by the id (preferably a `const` and a non-`const` overload). It isn't as nice as `[ ]` and maybe doesn't even reduce the writing that much, but it makes clear that you are indexing by the object.

Comment: OK, just forget about insertions. How much faster will be the vector for accessing.

Comment: The difference is likely not significant in most applications. Use the one best suited to the problem.

Comment: @yui, both technically have constant lookup time; but hash lookup has more overhead. How often do you do lookups? Once, twice? Probably doesn't matter either way. Thousands, tens of thousands, use a vector.

Comment: You only have a 1000 elements. Why can't you just test the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Generally:

Vector has better cache coherence due to lack of indirection. Accessing an index is faster because there is no need to calculate a hash function. Iteration has predictable branches.

Unordered map uses less memory with sparse structures (you said that indices are continuous, so this advantage does not apply to you). Adding or removing elements in arbitrary indices is asymptotically faster with unordered map.

Asymptotic complexity doesn't necessarily matter when you have only very few elements such as 100-1000. Cache coherency and branch prediction tend to dominate in this case.

First pick which ever data structure is more convenient. Then measure if accessing that structure has significant impact on performance of the program as a whole. If it does, then measure the difference with the other data structure to see if it is significantly faster (in relation to variance of measurement).

Answer (score 0):

### Use the most convenient container for the task

**Generally speaking.**

If you have something like `100-1000` elements, the container doesn't really matter in itself - using a `std::map` even is better than `std::unordered_map` for example if you ever need to debug print the content - unless you somehow rely on the hash. It's when you get to something like 100k+ elements that container performance starts to get interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I just wondered about the same question. Although I generally agree that one should in most cases use the most convenient container and also that, when in doubt, you should measure yourself, I think it is nice to have at least a general idea of the dimensions we're talking about.

Hence, I implemented a small example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

struct MyStruct {
    int value;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    size_t const SIZE = 100;
    size_t const ACCESSES = 10000;

    std::vector<MyStruct const*> my_structs;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        my_structs.push_back(new MyStruct());
    }
    
    std::vector<double> values_vec(my_structs.size());
    std::unordered_map<MyStruct const*, double> values_map;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        double rand_val = (rand() % 1000)/10;

        values_vec[i] = rand_val;
        values_map[my_structs[i]] = rand_val;
    }

    std::vector<MyStruct const*> queries_ptr;
    std::vector<size_t> queries_int;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ACCESSES; ++i) {
        size_t idx = rand() % SIZE;
        queries_int.push_back(idx);
        queries_ptr.push_back(my_structs[idx]);
    }

    auto begin_vec = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double large_sum_vec = 0;
    for (size_t query : queries_int) {
        large_sum_vec += values_vec[query];
    }
    auto end_vec = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    double large_sum_map = 0;
    for (MyStruct const* query : queries_ptr) {
        large_sum_map += values_map[query];
    }
    auto end_map = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Results for " << ACCESSES << " accesses to vector of size " << SIZE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=== VEC === Result = " << large_sum_vec << " Time = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_vec - begin_vec).count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "=== MAP === Result = " << large_sum_vec << " Time = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_map - end_vec).count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        delete my_structs[i];
    }
}
```

You can find it here on Coliru:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a986dd2607a8566a

The result:
**std::vector with indices is about 10-20 times faster than std::unordered_map for random read-access**

Interestingly, both running times are almost independent of the data size. With increasing numbers of accesses the relation shifts more towards 1:20. I did not test write-intensive / mixed, but I don't expect that there is much of a difference, since the element is already found at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`vector` vs `map` have critical differences in how they treat keys. Ignore performance, and use whichever one has the right behavior for keys when a node is inserted or deleted in the middle.

In general, if you're mapping ids to values, the right behavior is that when a node is deleted, then other items keys should not change, and therefore a `map` is the best choice.  It is the least surprising container, and contains the least surprising behavior for this task, and developers will therefore generate the fewest number of bugs in surrounding code.

If you have less than ~1000 items, then performance doesn't matter. If, however, you've **measured** that this code is actually affecting performance, and you're also 100% certain that values are never inserted or removed while the "map" is alive, then `std::vector` is actually far faster to be created, initialized, and used. However, if you use a `std::vector`, then developers are likely to make incorrect assumptions in surrounding code, and the code will likely eventually generate bugs, so you definitely only want to make this switch if it **measurably** makes a big difference in app performance. It doesn't matter how fast your app is, if it's wrong.

Comment: The question specifically asks about the performance. Answers like this are extremely unhelpful, and mostly sounds like a way to sound smart and put down the op. You do not know the kind of problem that he/she is trying to solve, so how can you say "ignore performance"? You dont know if the problem that is time critical or not, or how frequent the lookups are performed. It may be the main hot path in the OPs application.

Comment: That's a fair point, and this answer is not a good one. I'll improve it.  However, it does lack quite enough information to give the best answer.